# How can i add timezone in my code for countdown timer

Tags: javascript

Hi please help how can i add timezone the depends on the current time of my pc or mobile. this code is for my landing page. Thanks

Here is my code..

// Create Countdown

var Countdown = {

// Backbone-like structure
  $el: $('.countdown'),

// Params
  countdown_interval: null,
  total_seconds     : 0,

// Initialize the countdown

init: function() {

```
// DOM
    this.$ = {
    days  : this.$el.find('.bloc-time.days .figure'),
    hours  : this.$el.find('.bloc-time.hours .figure'),
    minutes: this.$el.find('.bloc-time.min .figure'),
    seconds: this.$el.find('.bloc-time.sec .figure')

};

// Init countdown values
this.values = {
    days  : this.$.days.parent().attr('data-init-value'),
    hours  : this.$.hours.parent().attr('data-init-value'),
    minutes: this.$.minutes.parent().attr('data-init-value'),
    seconds: this.$.seconds.parent().attr('data-init-value'),
};
// Initialize total seconds
this.total_seconds = this.values.days * 60 * 60 * 60 + (this.values.hours * 60 * 60) + (this.values.minutes * 60) + this.values.seconds;

// Animate countdown to the end
this.count();
```

},

count: function() {

```
var that    = this,
    $day_1 = this.$.days.eq(0),
    $day_2 = this.$.days.eq(1),
    $hour_1 = this.$.hours.eq(0),
    $hour_2 = this.$.hours.eq(1),
    $min_1  = this.$.minutes.eq(0),
    $min_2  = this.$.minutes.eq(1),
    $sec_1  = this.$.seconds.eq(0),
    $sec_2  = this.$.seconds.eq(1);

    this.countdown_interval = setInterval(function() {

    if(that.total_seconds > 0) {

        --that.values.seconds;

        if(that.values.minutes >= 0 && that.values.seconds < 0) {

            that.values.seconds = 59;
            --that.values.minutes;
        }

        if(that.values.hours >= 0 && that.values.minutes < 0) {

            that.values.minutes = 59;
            --that.values.hours;
        }

        if(that.values.days >= 0 && that.values.hours < 0) {

            that.values.hours = 24;
            --that.values.days;
        }

        // Update DOM values
        // Days
        that.checkHour(that.values.days, $day_1, $day_2);

        // Hours
        that.checkHour(that.values.hours, $hour_1, $hour_2);

        // Minutes
        that.checkHour(that.values.minutes, $min_1, $min_2);

        // Seconds
        that.checkHour(that.values.seconds, $sec_1, $sec_2);

        --that.total_seconds;
    }
    else {


        clearInterval(that.countdown_interval);

        document.getElementsByClassName('countdown')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementsByClassName("countdown-ex")[0].innerHTML = "EXPIRED!";


    }
}, 1000);
```

},

animateFigure: function($el, value) {

```
 var that         = this,
     $top         = $el.find('.top'),
     $bottom      = $el.find('.bottom'),
     $back_top    = $el.find('.top-back'),
     $back_bottom = $el.find('.bottom-back');

// Before we begin, change the back value
$back_top.find('span').html(value);

// Also change the back bottom value
$back_bottom.find('span').html(value);

// Then animate
TweenMax.to($top, 0.8, {
    rotationX           : '-180deg',
    transformPerspective: 300,
      ease                : Quart.easeOut,
    onComplete          : function() {

        $top.html(value);

        $bottom.html(value);

        TweenMax.set($top, { rotationX: 0 });
    }
});

TweenMax.to($back_top, 0.8, {
    rotationX           : 0,
    transformPerspective: 300,
      ease                : Quart.easeOut,
    clearProps          : 'all'
});
```

},

checkHour: function(value, $el_1, $el_2) {

```
var val_1       = value.toString().charAt(0),
    val_2       = value.toString().charAt(1),
    fig_1_value = $el_1.find('.top').html(),
    fig_2_value = $el_2.find('.top').html();

if(value >= 10) {

    // Animate only if the figure has changed
    if(fig_1_value !== val_1) this.animateFigure($el_1, val_1);
    if(fig_2_value !== val_2) this.animateFigure($el_2, val_2);
}
else {

    // If we are under 10, replace first figure with 0
    if(fig_1_value !== '0') this.animateFigure($el_1, 0);
    if(fig_2_value !== val_1) this.animateFigure($el_2, val_1);
}
```

}
};

// Let's go !

Countdown.init();

Answer (score 0):

Use moment.js with the moment-timezone add on ([link](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)), which supports time zone guessing with

```
moment.tz.guess().
```

If you can guarantee your users are running a browser that supports the brand new ECMAScript Internationalization API, you can get the user's time zone like this:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

Reference: [Support for ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)

Comment: First, what do you want to make use of it except displaying it on your landing page?

Comment: hi i already found a solution for it.. i have another question if its ok with you how can i make the countdown timer not to reset while refresh the page?

Comment: You should store the countdown time somewhere else, like cookies or localstorage, and then retrieve it and do the countdown again when the page finishes reloading.

Comment: hi i am new on local storage how can i add it in my code?

Comment: You can check out the examples in the documentation on MDN, it's quite easy and straightforward to catch on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage